# Githook to msg on change to specific directory

Tags: git, githooks

How would one go about writing a post-receive hook that does something when there is change to a specific directory on the master branch? So far I figured out how to determine if the push involves the master branch, but I'm working on determining if the given directory has changed. I assume I have to do some git magic here.

In this case I want to check if there are any changes in the `schema/` directory. This is all I have so far, which I grabbed from the docs.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo POST-RECEIVE
while read oldrev newrev refname
do
    branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref $refname)
    if [ "master" == "$branch" ]; then
        do_something $oldrev $newrev $refname
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a `git diff --name-only $oldrev $newrev` and check the output for your path.

Answer (score 0):

This suits my needs for now.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo POST-RECEIVE
while read oldrev newrev refname
do
    branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref $refname)
    if [ "master" == "$branch" ]; then
        git diff --quiet --exit-code $oldrev $newrev -- schema/ || echo SUCCESS
    fi
done
```